# Magento Cookies and database work on page load

Tags: events, magento, observer-pattern

I want to do some database operations and get/set a cookie before the front page loads.  for which event would i make the observer?  I haven't gotten to the cookie creation yet in my research, right now i want to do some database manipulation at the event.  I have an observer right now going off at `controller_front_send_response_before` and this is the error trace i'm getting.

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/" already exists

Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(192): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(446): Mage::register('_singleton/', false)
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1252): Mage::getSingleton(false)
#3 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_fron...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(186): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_fron...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(340): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(627): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/index.php(86): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

This is my config node:

```
<frontend>
    ... 
    <events>
        <controller_front_send_response_before>
            <observers>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Foo_Bar_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>controllerFrontSendResponseBefore</method>
            </observers>
        </controller_front_send_response_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

And this is my observer model

```
class Foo_Bar_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerFrontSendResponseBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
         $id = 1;
         $theVisitors = Mage::getModel('visitors/visitor');
         $theVisitors->load($id);  
         $numVisits = (int)$theVisitors->getNumvisits();
         ++$numVisits;
         $theVisitors->setNumvisits($numVisits);
         $theVisitors->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the switch statement in `Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent()`. You aren't declaring a `<model>` node in your observer configuration - you have a `<class>` node. *Interestingly, `Mage::getSingleton()` is poorly coded. The test to see if the singleton instance should be created and registered doesn't handle the prototyped key of `_singleton/`*!

Now for your cookie. Mmm cookies. You're observing a proper event for cookie manipulation (evident in the comment from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::dispatch()`). You can also observe `controller_action_predispatch`. These will trigger for every page view, though, so you need to implement first-time-visitor logic in your observer. Also, you might have some dumbed-down code as an example here, but obviously the front page isn't the only initial point of entry (I assumes that's what you are going to do with cookies). There is an easily-targeted event in the CMS router, `Mage_Cms_Controller_Router` - you can use that for home page views.

I'd be remiss to not tell you that there is a visitor logging mechanism in place (see the `log_*` tables).

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm.  Stupid omission on my part there.  Now to tackle getting the cookies to be set with the enterprise full page cache enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Are you working with the community edition or Magento Enterprise? If you are using Magento Enterprise, and a page is fully served by the Full Page Cache module (Enterprise_PageCache), no events will be fired. This means that your code would be only triggered the first time around when no (full) cache was available. The following visitors will get the website served from cache, thus without any events triggered.

The reason is, that with FPC enabled (and primed), Magento serves all the content without actually running the full application. This also results in an empty observer collection, thus nothing to dispatch. Your custom observer will not be triggered.

As far as I know the only way to get this working in FPC mode is by punching a hole for each unique user to force Magento to initialize the application and thus trigger all regular events in the process and reaching your custom code.

If you run community you have nothing to worry about. Unless you are also running a FPC variant for community like TinyBrick's LightSpeed module.

Comment: I am working with FPC enabled.  Funny, i got the whole thing working on our dev server (where fpc isn't enabled) and went to test it with fpc and it obviously diddnt work since the event i was catching never was dispatched. Did some research, the hole-punching method works well for front end blocks, but not so much for the cookies.  I dug around and found that magento has a javascript cookie library in /js/mage/Cookies.js .  I added some javascript using that library to generate the cookies i need to the html header using our theme's local.xml and everything works great.

Answer (score 0):

this type of problem is related to the compilation magento

should think about doing a compilation

go to settings / tools / compiler or by command line : php shell / compil.php -- compile

khadija